# Why does my app return 304 status code when started with node but not with nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

I've created a basic app which can take notes, and I'm using a .json file to store them. This is part of an assignment where I was given the front-end code and then had to create the Express back end.

Throughout development I used nodemon to run the server, but I needed to host on heroku so I've changed it to start with node instead, however now my GET requests in the fetch method are returning 304, even when the database has definitely been modified. POST and DELETE both still work and modify the database but GET doesn't even after refreshing the page. I have to stop the server and start it again for the fetch request to work.

The code making the request:

```
const getNotes = () =>
  fetch('/api/notes', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  });
```

Express code used to respond:

```
app.get('/api/notes', (req, res) => res.json(database));
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: When you modify the database via POST or DELETE, do you mirror the changes you make to the json file to the in-memory representation of the database?

Comment: @IAmDranged I believe so, for example the method used to handle the POST request is:
```
 fs.readFile('./db/db.json', 'utf8', (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }
            dataObject = (JSON.parse(data));
            req.body.id = uuid();
            dataObject.push(req.body);
            writeToDatabase(JSON.stringify(dataObject));
        });
```

Comment: Based on this code you actually don't. More specifically you don't update the `database` variable you are using in your `app.get('/api/notes')` route handler. You can get away with it when running your server with nodemon since it restarts your server every time a change is made to your json file - reloading by doing so a fresh database in memory -, but not with node.

Comment: @IAmDranged Ah I get it now! I misunderstood how `const database = require('./db/db.json');` would work, I thought it would retrieve a "live" version of the .json file every time it was used. I replaced `res.json` with `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './db/db.json'));` and it now works perfectly. Thank you for your help